# generating proxy classes by using command prompt

Tags: web-services

I have generated a proxy classes for web service by using wsimport commands.
While generating I got a error like this:

> [WARNING] SOAP port "ServiceSoap12":
>   uses a non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding.
>   line 138 of
>   http://10.0.3.24/Test/service.asmx?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug - wsimport processes by default SOAP 1.1, which is standard.

https://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/wsimport-problem-ignoring-soap-port-ws2007federationhttpbindingihelloservice-it-uses-non-st